# Adjust right-side text within plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, figure

I would like to print some text on the right-side of every stacked bar. I have found a way to do it, by annotating, but there are some problems: the `autolabel` function seems to me like a very superfluous way to annotate, is there anything simpler for achieving the same visual effect, easier? And more importantly, how can I fix this text overrunning the right side of the figure, as you can see below? I have tried to `subplots_adjust`, but didn't quite work...

[image]

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the x-axis label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()#(figsize=(6, 4), dpi=200)
# FOR SIDE-BY-SIDE plotting:
# rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
# rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')
rects1 = ax.bar(x, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, women_means, width, bottom=men_means, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + 3 * rect.get_width() / 2, rect.get_y() + height / 2),
                    xytext=(0, -5),
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='center')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.9, right=1.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The text overrrunning can be fixed by slightly adjusting the x limit: `ax_xl=ax.get_xlim()` and then `ax.set_xlim((ax_xl[0], 1.05 * ax_xl[1]))`. To make it fit simply adjust the factor `1.05`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind your rightmost bar being slightly off-centre from the tick label, you could just move it to the left slightly so that your label fits.

If you print what gets returned by the call to `bar()` you see it's a `BarContainer` object with 5 artists:

```py
<BarContainer object of 5 artists>
```

... which you can iterate over:

```py
Rectangle(xy=(-0.175, 0), width=0.35, height=20, angle=0)
Rectangle(xy=(0.825, 0), width=0.35, height=34, angle=0)
Rectangle(xy=(1.825, 0), width=0.35, height=30, angle=0)
Rectangle(xy=(2.825, 0), width=0.35, height=35, angle=0)
Rectangle(xy=(3.825, 0), width=0.35, height=27, angle=0)
```

Each `Rectangle` object has a [set_xy()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.set_xy) method. So you can move the final upper and lower bar in the following way:

```py
bar, bar2 = rects1[4], rects2[4]
bar.set_xy((bar.get_x()-0.05,bar.get_y()))
bar2.set_xy((bar2.get_x()-0.05,bar2.get_y()))
```

by putting the above code just below your

```py
rects1 = ax.bar(x, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x, women_means, width, bottom=men_means, label='Women')
```

and by removing your call to `subplots_adjust()`, and using `tight_layout()` instead, I was able to achieve this:

[image: first_option]

Alternatively, if you don't mind the spacing between the label and the bar reducing you could just change `rect.get_x() + 3` to `rect.get_x() + 2.5` in the `autolabel()` function, to give you this:
[image: second_option]